# object 'MEDV' not found -> but MEDV is in data set

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I'm trying to write the equation to predict the median, first I need to fit a multiple linear regression model to the median house price (MEDV) as a function of CRIM, CHAS, and RM.

```
BostonHousing
n.training <- floor(nrow(data)*0.7) 
id.training <- sample(1:nrow(data), n.training)
data.training <- data[id.training,]
data.test <- data[-id.training,]
mlr1 <-lm(MEDV ~ CRIM+CHAS+RM,data=data.training)
```

#Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'CAT..MEDV' not found

I get an error in line 6 saying that MEDV is an object not found but it is on the file.

Comment: We don't see your data ... but MEDV has to be a column name in data.training. Take a look at data.training if you did not misspell it and there is really a column exactly named MEDV.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, the column MEDV does exist, I checked already. How can I post my data?

Comment: If the data isn't too extensive you can type: dput(data.training) and post the result here, then we can copy it and we have the data in the same form like you have it

Comment: I got it!! It wasn't connected to the correct data, my RStudio was getting another database. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line was wrong `mlr1 <-lm(MEDV ~ CRIM+CHAS+RM,data=data.training)` -> data should be `data=BostonHousing`

Comment: you can accept your own answer to show that the question was solved

Answer (score 0):

From the ISLR2 package...

```r
lm.fit <-lm(medv ~ crim + chas + rm, data = Boston)
summary(lm.fit)
```